# iOS state restoration issue with DrawerController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, xcode8

I have an app written in Swift 3.1, using Xcode 8.3.3.

I am currently trying to implement state preservation/restoration.

To do this I have implemented `shouldSaveApplicationState` and `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` methods in `AppDelegate.swift` and set to return `true`:

```
// AppDelegate.swift
// STATE RESTORATION CALLBACKS

func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    debug_print(this: "shouldSaveApplicationState")
    return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    debug_print(this: "shouldRestoreApplicationState")
    restoringState = true
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    debug_print(this: "willFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
    return true
}
```

I’ve also provided restoration IDs for all involved viewcontrollers and navigationcontrollers.

I'm using a 3rd party library to handle side drawer navigation container  (https://github.com/sascha/DrawerController). The initial viewcontroller is set programmatically inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, see below.

```
// AppDelegate.swift
var centerContainer: DrawerController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let centerViewController =   mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootViewControllerNav") as! UINavigationController 
    let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideDrawerViewController") as! UITableViewController

    centerContainer = DrawerController(centerViewController: centerViewController, leftDrawerViewController: leftViewController)

    centerContainer?.restorationIdentifier = "DrawerControllerView"
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.restorationIdentifier = "MainWindow"
    window?.rootViewController = centerContainer
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

When app opens and attempts to restore state, it displays the correct viewcontroller (last controller before app closed) temporarily, then once app becomes active it reverts back to the initial viewcontroller.

For example, the following happens:

1. Open app Navigate to the “settings” view via the side menu
2. Navigate to the home screen
3. Stop running xcode and start it again
4. App will open showing settings view, then revert back to home view

Can anyone tell me what is causing this, or where I am going wrong? Let me know if you need any more code examples.

Comment: you also need to implement `static func viewController(withRestorationIdentifierPath identifierComponents: [Any], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? ` in the Controller that you wish to be restored

Comment: Thanks @Lamar, I implemented the method you suggested and managed to get it working.

Comment: you welcome. I think you should add your answer in your question so you could help someone else with the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let leftSideDrawerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideDrawerViewController") as! UITableViewController
        let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootViewControllerNav") as! UINavigationController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
        navigationController.restorationIdentifier = "navigationControllerKey"
        let leftSideNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftSideDrawerViewController)
        leftSideNavController.restorationIdentifier = "LeftNavigationController"
        self.drawerController = DrawerController(centerViewController: navigationController, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNavController, rightDrawerViewController: nil)
        self.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = .all
        self.drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = .all
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.drawerController
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to explain your answer at all? A block of code isn't all that helpful if you don't explain where it goes or what it does.

Comment: facing the similar issue. it would be great if someone explains with code.